# Echo line containing grep -c output only if that output is nonzero

Tags: bash

I have the following code

```
...
year_a=2018
year_b=2021

for (( i=year_b; i>=year_a; i-=1 )); do
  printf "$i: "; grep -Eic "A-15-" <<< "$results"
done
...
```

Output:

```
2021: 0   
2020: 11
2019: 0
2018: 21
```

I wish to make the following output:

```
2020: 11 
2018: 21
```

i.e., print a year if *grep* gave a return output which is not equal to zero, but I don't quite understand how to build such a construction. It is necessary to execute the first command if the second has found the outcome. Maybe somebody can give me a direction, thank you.

Comment: What does your input data look like please? And, forgetting abouf `grep` and exit statuses, what are you trying to do in simple English? Thank you.

Comment: How do you get different results from the same search and from the same input?

Answer (score 2):

If you *capture* the output into a shell variable (instead of letting it be printed directly to the terminal), you can then only conditionally print it:

```
if resultCount=$(grep -Eic "A-15-" <<< "$results"); then
  echo "$i: $resultCount"
fi
```

This works because `grep` returns a zero (successful) exit status if-and-only-if it finds at least one match; and storing the command substitution's result does not itself modify exit status.

See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results with a `grep` after the loop.

```
for (( i=year_b; i>=year_a; i-=1 )); do
  printf "$i: "; grep -Eic "A-15-" <<< "$results"
done | grep -v " 0$"
```